# Is it possible to get the balance without the decimals or a specific amount of decimals?

Tags: flutter, dart, metamask

I am using the [web3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3) package and I am getting the balance like so

```
final abi = [
  'function balanceOf(address) view returns (uint)',
];

final token = web3.Contract(
  '{contract address}',
  abi,
  web3.provider!,
);

final balance = await token.call<BigInt>(
  'balanceOf',
  ['{walletAddress}'],
);

print('BALANCE: ${balance}');
```

But when I print the balance I notice it also has the decimals. How can I get the balance without the decimals? Or with a specific amount of decimals? Or read what amount of decimals have been set on the token details?

My balance is 999987 and I get 999987000000000000000000

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `package:web3` and with cryptocurrencies in general, but are the number of unwanted digits actually variable?  Can you not just divide your result by `BigInt.from(10).pow(18)`?

Comment: But how do I know if someone has set the amount of decimals to 18 on importing the token

Comment: As I said, I'm unfamiliar with cryptocurrencies.  Is that something that individuals can set?

Comment: Yes you can set it when you import a token. And you can find it at token details in metamask for example.

Comment: Have you tried `token.call<BigInt>('decimals', ...)`?

Comment: It looks like the `web3` package has [`CurrencyParams.decimals`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_web3/latest/ethereum/CurrencyParams/decimals.html) and [`ContractERC20.decimals`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_web3/latest/ethers/ContractERC20/decimals.html).  I'm guessing one of them does what you want.

Comment: The balanceOf is the abi function I try to call.  Which is documented here https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/ as found on the web3 package readme. There is no decimals abi functions or something that returns a result in that direction it seems.

Comment: @jamesdlin that seems to be for adding a chain https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_web3/latest/ethereum/Ethereum/walletAddChain.html. What I am trying to do is get tokens from a chain that is alreaddy added.

Comment: @jamesdlin you were right there was a decimals function

Comment: I posted an answer for now but if you post one I will accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James suggested there is a decimals function

```
const abi = [
  'function balanceOf(address) view returns (uint)',
  'function decimals() view returns (uint)',
];

final token = web3.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  abi,
  web3.provider!,
);

final balance = await token.call<BigInt>(
  'decimals',
  [],
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `'toInt()'` method. Like, `'balance.toInt()'`

Comment: balance.toInt() gives me  9.99987e+23 where it should be 999987

Answer (score -1):

Use [Decimal.fromBigInt](https://pub.dev/documentation/decimal/latest/decimal/Decimal/Decimal.fromBigInt.html) to create `Decimal` and then round as desired.